# How do we declare jms queue in application.properties of spring boot

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, jms

Below snippet is available in servlet.xml of Tomcat

```
 <Resource name="jms/queue/NotificationQ" 
      auth="Container"        
      type="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" 
      factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory"  
      physicalName="NotificationQ"/>
```

and in **context.xml**

```
 <ResourceLink name="jms/queue/NotificationQ" global="jms/queue/NotificationQ"/>
```

Now I am in the process of creating a standalone war file using spring boot. How do I declare the jms queue in spring boot, so that the above configuration works with embedded tomcat?

Comment: Why even bother with a JNDI version of this? Just let Spring Boot create connection factory and queues. Trying to use JNDI with an embedded tomcat only complicates things and doesn't add anything.

Comment: Actually we are testing this with our existing project and to limit resource usage, queues are hosted in different environment. Also activemq and websphere we switch accordingly based on load. In such a case if we consume queue it would be really helpful. Any suggestions or examples will greatly help